# How to define an http4s server as a ZIO ZLayer to be injected and fetched in the main?

Tags: scala, http4s, cats-effect, zio

Help me define an http4s using ZLayers. I'm learning and I'm confused. I'd like to factor out the http server as a component. But I don't know how to compose the ZManageds and the the ZLayers so that it would compile.

Also does it makes sense to create a layer that requires a `Runtime[ZEnv]`? Or does that make more sense to create a layer that requires a `ZEnv` and generate the runtime for it.

```
object HttpServer {

  def createHttp4Server: ZManaged[Runtime[ZEnv], Throwable, Server] = 
      ZManaged.accessManaged { implicit runtime: Runtime[ZEnv] =>
        BlazeServerBuilder[Task](runtime.platform.executor.asEC)
          .bindHttp(8080, "localhost")
          .withHttpApp(Routes.helloWorldService)
          .resource
          .toManagedZIO
      }


  def createHttp4Layer: ZLayer[RuntimeLayer, Throwable, Http4ServerLayer] =
    ZLayer.succeed(createHttp4Server)

}

object Routes {
  val helloWorldService = ...
}
```

```
package object simple {
  type Http4ServerLayer = Has[ZManaged[Runtime[ZEnv], Throwable, Server]]
  type RuntimeLayer = Has[Runtime[ZEnv]]
}
```

I don't know how to access the `ZManaged[..., ..., Server]` from the `Layer` in here in the main.
I don't understand the `access` methods completely.

```
object ItsAren extends App {

  def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = {

    val toProvide: ZIO[Http4ServerLayer, Nothing, ExitCode] =
      ZIO
        .accessM[Http4ServerLayer](_.get.useForever) //compile error
        .as(ExitCode.success)
        .catchAll(ZIO.succeed(ExitCode.failure))

    val runtimeLayer: ZLayer[Any, Nothing, RuntimeLayer]              = ZLayer.succeed(Runtime.default)
    val http4Layer: ZLayer[RuntimeLayer, Throwable, Http4ServerLayer] = HttpServer.createHttp4Layer
    val fullLayer: ZLayer[Any, Throwable, Http4ServerLayer]           = runtimeLayer >>> http4Layer

    val provided = toProvide.provideCustomLayer(fullLayer)

    provided //compile error
  }

}
```

```
type mismatch
 found   : ZIO[Runtime[ZEnv], Throwable, Nothing]
 required: ZIO[Http4ServerLayer, ?, ?]
```

also at the bottom, but that's lower importance

```
 found   : ZIO[ZEnv, Throwable, ExitCode]
 required: URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode]
```

Same thing in a PR, feel free to comment
https://github.com/kovacshuni/itsaren/pull/1

Comment: Solved, soon I'm posting the result.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is that a ZLayer when holding a Managed, is a Managed itself. So when something is running on a layer like this, the included Managed will be used through that time. So if you run a `ZIO.never` on a layer, the server will be kept alive.

To build the layer itself was another trick to use `fromManaged`. And the `createHttp4Server` requires a `ZEnv` only, no point in requiring a `Runtime` I admit now. `ZManaged.runtime` is another trick they have for not to use `ZManaged.accessManaged { implicit runtime: Runtime[ZEnv] =>`.

Full solution https://github.com/kovacshuni/zio-http4s-zlayer-example

```scala
object Main extends App {

  def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = {

    val program: ZIO[Has[Server] with Console, Nothing, Nothing] =
      ZIO.never

    val httpServerLayer: ZLayer[ZEnv, Throwable, Http4Server] = Http4Server.createHttp4sLayer

    program
      .provideLayer(httpServerLayer ++ Console.live)
      .exitCode
  }

}
```

```scala
import zio._
import zio.interop.catz._
import zio.interop.catz.implicits._

import org.http4s.server.Server
import org.http4s.server.blaze.BlazeServerBuilder

object Http4Server {

  type Http4Server = Has[Server]

  def createHttp4Server: ZManaged[ZEnv, Throwable, Server] =
    ZManaged.runtime[ZEnv].flatMap { implicit runtime: Runtime[ZEnv] =>
      BlazeServerBuilder[Task](runtime.platform.executor.asEC)
        .bindHttp(8080, "localhost")
        .withHttpApp(Routes.helloWorldService)
        .resource
        .toManagedZIO
    }

  def createHttp4sLayer: ZLayer[ZEnv, Throwable, Http4Server] =
    ZLayer.fromManaged(createHttp4Server)

}
```